# SAT Math probability and repeats

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A ball's area is divided into two sections. If each section is to be painted using one of 5 different colors, how many differently painted designs are possible?

I know that the first area has 5 options for coloring. The second area has 4 options for coloring so 5x4 = total possibilities for differently painted designs.

I'm not sure if 5x4 would include repeats? Can you explain why the solution for the problem, 5x4, would not include repeats?

Comment: hard to say without knowing exactly what's meant by section

Comment: Amazingly badly worded for a SAT question, ambiguities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an incredibly ambiguous problem!  Here are four answers.

1. Suppose the two sections are of different shapes or sizes.  To be specific, let's say one is one octant ($\frac{1}{8}$ of the ball's surface) and the other is the remaining $\frac{7}{8}$.  Then there are $5$ options for colouring each section, total $5^2=25$.
2. Suppose that the ball is divided as in the previous case, but we insist that it must be possible to tell where the two sections are by looking at the coloured ball.  Then the sections must be painted in different colours, so the number of options is $5\times4=20$.
3. Suppose that the ball is divided into two equal hemispheres, and that we can look at the ball from any direction we like.  Then colouring the hemispheres, say, red and blue will be the same as blue and red.  So colours must be chosen with order unimportant, giving $C(5,2)=10$ possibilities; plus $5$ more if the hemispheres have the same colour, total $10+5=15$.
4. As in 3., but the single colour option is disallowed, so there are only $C(5,2)=10$ options.

You could also specify that the ball is divided into two hemispheres, but that it is not moved and is always viewed from the same direction.  This would be the same as case 1.  Or maybe 2.

So to sum up, I would say the answer is $25,20,15$ or $10$, depending what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you paint the first section with colour 1, then there are 4 colors left to paint the second section with another color. You go on like this, if you paint the first section with the other 4 colors-and always different colors in section 2.
Here the sections are never painted with the same color at the same time.

greetings,

calculus